# Refine grep look behind to avoid numbers

Tags: linux, bash, grep, docker

When I query `docker images`, I get this:

```
#> docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG            IMAGE ID           CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
local/debian        7.5            172c7702a46f       2 weeks ago         175.1 MB
local/debian        wheezy         172c7702a46f       2 weeks ago         175.1 MB
```

Using `grep` I extract the image tags:

```
#> docker images | grep -oP '\S+(?=\s+172c7702a46f)'
7.5
wheezy
```

How can I refine this to get `wheezy` only and avoid anything that matches `\d+\.\d+`?

Comment: You can easily solve this by reading the `grep` manpage. As an alternative, you can also use `awk`: `docker images | awk '$2!~/[[:digit:]]/{print $2}'`.

Comment: You are right ... I end up with `docker images | grep -oP '\S+(?=\s+172c7702a46f)' | grep -vP '\d+\.\d+'`. Took me an eternity to understand why `-o` in the second `grep` did not yield anything ... woudl have preferred forgoingn the second `grep` though. Can all of that be packed into a single regexp?

Comment: Add `[a-z]` before `\S+` to match `y` from wheezy: `grep -oP '[a-z]\S+(?=\s+172c7702a46f)'`.

Answer (score 1):

The `grep` expression is too complicated. Use `awk` for a more straightforward, clear solution that doesn't required a regex wizard to read:

```
docker images | awk '$3 == "172c7702a46f" && $2 ~ /^[a-z]/ {print $2}'
```

That is: if column 3 is 172c7702a46f, and column 2 starts with letters, print column 2.

Comment: Look ahead / look behind are common regex notions. That's not *too complicated*, the only thing is : people are not used to regex flavours in a general way and call everything complicated once it goes further than `[a-z0-9]`  stuff. It's also more concise and faster at runtime to write `grep -oP '[[:alpha:]]+(?=[[:space:]]+172c7702a46f)'` than a bunch of awk conditions.